# How set a variable as the differance of 2 other variables in oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am new to Oracle, and I have a class registration type database, and I am using a Stored Procedure to print the Available Courses for a certain semseter. I am currently trying to set the "Remaining open Spots" of a class as the difference between the ***Capacity - Registered.*** But I am not sure how / where to create this variable as the difference between 2 other variables,So that I may use it in my table.

Can anyone help?  Everything I have now works fine, I just need help with this variable.  I am thinking I create and set the variable in the Select statement, then I can just use the variable in my Table.  I just dont know how.

```
for i in (select Course_Id, Capacity, Registered, Semester, City from Schedule)
  loop
    if(i.Semester = Semcode AND i.City = City) then
    htp.print('      <tr>');
     htp.print('        <td>'||i.Semester||'</td>');
    htp.print('        <td>'||i.Course_Id||'</td>');
    htp.print('        <td>'||i.Capacity||'</td>');
    htp.print('        <td>'||i.Registered||'</td>');
    /*htp.print('        <td>'||********* "Remaing Spots Variable"******* ||'</td>');*/
    htp.print('      </tr>');
    end if;
  end loop;
```

Comment: Have you tried `htp.print('        <td>'|| ( i.Capacity - i.Registered ) ||'</td>');` ?

Comment: @kordirko Yes I have, This way just makes my html page error out and say "Page not found"

Comment: @kordirko  aahhhh, it works the with (  ).  If you put that as an answer I will chose it. Thank you

Comment: If this doesn't work, then try to declare a variable in the declaration part of the procedure (somewhere between IS and BEGIN keywords), for example; `my_variable NUMBER;`, and assign a value to variable in the loop (after the LOOP keyword): `my_variable := i.Capacity - i.Registered;`, and use it in a call to htp : `htp.print('        <td>'||my_variable||'</td>');`

Comment: @kordirko you original suggestion worked after I added the ( ). Paste that into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's fairly easy:

```
SQL> select 'hello'||(5-3)||'goodbye' from dual;

'HELLO'||(5-3
-------------
hello2goodbye
```

-> in your case it would just be (i.Capacity - i.Registered) ... though it's important those fields are number / integer / somethinglikethis (it won't work with varchar2)